# how to appened objects and array of objects into single array if id matches react hooks or react or react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

if group id of API matches heading id, take Group Name from heading and menus from API and make array exactly like SampleArray.

```
const [newArray, setNewArray]=useState([])

let heading = [                
                  { ID: 3, Group Name: 'Medical Procedures' },
                  { ID: 5, Group Name: 'Insurance' },
                  { ID: 4, Group Name: 'Cash' },
                  { ID: 6, Group Name: 'Pharmacy' },
                  { ID: 7, Group Name: 'Inventory' },
                  { ID: 8, Group Name: 'Lab' },
              ]

const settingArray=()=>{    
         
        // UserRoleList is the data from API
           UserRoleList:[
                   {Dashboard:{GroupID:5,   Menu:  'Insurance Invoice'}},
                   {Dashboard:{GroupID:5,   Menu:  'Insurance Return'}},
                   {Dashboard:{GroupID:5,   Menu: 'Insurance Order'}},
                   {Dashboard:{GroupID:8,   Menu: 'Lab Order'}},
                   {Dashboard:{GroupID:8,   Menu: 'Lab Return'}},                  
                 ] 

//if Groupid matches the id, add Array    
       
setNewArray()
}
```

//below will be the final result which i want achieve

```
const [sampleArray, setSampleArray]=useState([         
                  {
                      Group Name :"Insurance", 
                      data:[
                            {Dashboard:{ Menu: 'Insurance Invoice'}},
                            {Dashboard:{ Menu: 'Insurance Return'}},
                            {Dashboard:{ Menu: 'Insurance Order'}},
                          ]
                  },
                  {
                      Group Name :"Lab ", 
                      data:[
                            {Dashboard:{ Menu: 'Lab Order'}},
                            {Dashboard:{ Menu: 'Lab Return'}},
                           ] 
                  },
         ])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
let heading = [
                  { ID: 3, Name: 'Medical Procedures' },
                  { ID: 5, Name: 'Insurance' },
                  { ID: 4, Name: 'Cash' },
                  { ID: 6, Name: 'Pharmacy' },
                  { ID: 7, Name: 'Inventory' },
                  { ID: 8, Name: 'Lab' },
];

let userRoleList = [
                   {Dashboard:{GroupID:5, Menu: 'Insurance Invoice'}},
                   {Dashboard:{GroupID:5, Menu: 'Insurance Return'}},
                   {Dashboard:{GroupID:5, Menu: 'Insurance Order'}},
                   {Dashboard:{GroupID:8, Menu: 'Lab Order'}},
                   {Dashboard:{GroupID:8, Menu: 'Lab Return'}},         ];
                   
const settingArray=()=>{
//The array that will setState
    const newSampleArray = [];
 //The first loop in heading
    heading.map(head=>{
  //Data Array
  const dataArray = [];
  // second loop to fill data array
    userRoleList.map(role =>{
        if (head.ID == role.Dashboard.GroupID){
        dataArray.push(role)
      }
    })
        newSampleArray.push({GroupName:head.Name,data:dataArray})
  })
  //setState here
  console.log(newSampleArray)
}

settingArray();
```

[JS Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/go2wf8ry/1/)

Comment: Thank you soo much...  your solution means a lot

Comment: if it helped you , mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in so others will know that it is the right solution.